# postgresql libpq C function with parameters

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I developed a function plpgsql that takes in an xml argument, parses the xmls and inserts into corresponding tables. It returns void after it finishes. I can co select functionname('xml string');

This will parse 'xml string' and insert into the destination table(s).

I want to invoke this using libpq.

```
const char *paramValues[1];
paramValues[0] = s.ptr;
char *stm = "select schema.LoadXML($1::xml)";
PGresult *res = PQexecParams(conn, stm, 1, NULL, paramValues, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

I was unable to find any example show how to invoke a function taking parameters.

Thanks in advance.

kd

Comment: 0) what does the `res` contain after the call? 1) Does it work for simple text string? 2) check the posthres logfile

Comment: Hi @wildplasser. This works. I had another statement that I was looking for an incorrect result code which threw me off.